# Wildcard subdomain on a subdomain in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, wildcard-subdomain

I want to create a wildcard sub-domain for a sub-domain something like *.abc.domain.com. Is it possible to create such a domain name in cpanel?

Also, when I create a wildcard sub-domain on main domain i.e. *.domain.com, then cpanel.domain.com goes where *.domain.com points. How to get cpanel login on cpanel.domain.com when *.domain.com is configured?

Answer (score 3):

You have asked two questions. Well, let me answer them separately.

1. 

> Answer to your first question is **dependent** on your **host**. If your host **supports** wildcard subdomains, in most cases wildcard ***sub-sub-domains*** are also **supported**. But a very **obvious condition** is that **abc.domain.com** must already **exist** before creating ***.abc.domain.com**
>
> > The answer for your second question is that **wildcard subdomains** always **resolve at the last.** ie. If you have both **subdomain.domain.com** and ***.domain.com** configured in your **cPanel**, only **non-existent subdomains** like **random1.domain.com** and **random2.domain.com** will **resolve** to ***.domain.com**. If anyone tries to access **subdomain.domain.com,** ***.domain.com** doesn't resolve because **subdomain.domain.com** already exists.
> >     
> >     So, If at present, you are able to access **cPanel** through **cpanel.domain.com,** there will surely be a **CNAME record** in your **DNS** as **cpanel.domain.com.** Since this already exists, your **wildcard** will **not resolve.** You should be able to **access cPanel** through **cpanel.domain.com** without any problem. If at all you are not able to access it, **domain.com:2082, domain.com:2083** and **domain.com/cpanel**(sometimes not) are always there.
> >
> > **Hope that helps...**

**Peace ...**

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how to create wildcards subdomains:
http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/

Be sure to wait until the propagation is over!